# Node JS: net.Socket is not a constructor

Tags: node.js

The below code works fine if I run it from my command line, but if I run this code anywhere in my project I get this error:

```
net.Socket is not a constructor
```

I've tried making the below code an object and importing / requiring it into my project and I still get that error.

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
    client.connect(3000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
});
```

Am I miss understanding what require does, I also tried using `import` and `import * as` to obtain 'net'.

I'm not too sure what information would be useful in the situation. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Are you running this code via node or browser? If from node, what version of node (`node -v`)?

Comment: It works fine if I run in via node, e.g. node test.js (it works), if I run it via my browser I get `net.createConnection is not a constructor` or `net.Socket is not a constructor`. Node version 4.4.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no plain TCP sockets in the browser, so that is why trying to use `net.Socket` in the browser (via webpack, browserify, etc.) won't work.

There could be a "polyfill" of sorts that requires a server to make the TCP connection on the browser's behalf though (or perhaps via some bridge to a Flash or Java applet).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into implementing polyfill to get it working.

Comment: @AdamEdney : Hi adam, I am getting the same issue, any updates in this

Comment: @Krishna I decided to use a websocket. i.e. https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket. Hope this helps!

Comment: @AdamEdney : Are you able to connect to any TCP server using  websocket or is it only work with the websocket server.

Comment: @javadeveloper To be honest I'm no expert, I have only tested it with a server that has web socket server.

Answer (score 0):

use node 16 version.
these features are currently under Node.js v16.9.1
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/net.html