# Getting error while trying to connect with postgres databse from react ES6

Tags: reactjs, postgresql

I am trying to set up a database connection from my existing react app.
But I am getting net.Socket is not a constructor error.
I have seen this [Node JS: net.Socket is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40599069/node-js-net-socket-is-not-a-constructor) but still can't figure out what should I do. I have tried using websocket but then I am getting some other exception -websocket is not a constructor.

Here is my code

```
import { Client } from 'pg';

const app = express();
const query = 'SELECT id, description, name, salary FROM public.usecase_details';
const client = new Client({
  user: 'out',
  host: 'pgn.example.com',
  database: 'salary_details',
  password: 'out',
  port: 1032,
});
client.connect();

client.query(query)
.then((res) => {
  console.log('Table is found');
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
})
.finally(() => {
  client.end();
});
```

Can I please get some idea/ help to solve this issue?

here are the  error details:
[image]

Comment: can we the code of the client ?

Comment: `pg` (full name: node-postgres) is a library meant for usage in a node.js environment. You cannot use it in the browser with react. You need an application server between the website and the database. How are you serving your html and js files?