# Create a tcp client in the vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, tcpclient

I try to create a tcp client in vue.js. I use this code below. but it gives to me error. that error is net.Socket() is not a constructor. How can I solve this problem or How can I create a client for tcp with another way. help please.

```
import net from 'net'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      ip: '192.168.1.118',
      port: '8085',
      message: 'test message',
      socket: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const socket = new net.Socket()
    this.socket = socket
    socket.on('data', (data) => console.log(data.toString()))
  },
  methods: {
    connect() {
      this.socket.connect(this.port, this.ip)
    },
    sendMessage() {
      this.socket.write(this.message)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `import net from 'net'` is available on node.js which is server side - browsers aren't node.js - you can't use server side only API's in a browser - and really, this has nothing to do with vue.js, just browsers in general - you *may* be able to achieve something with [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) - depending on the server side of course

Comment: so if I use `import net from 'net'` in the server side and I use websocket in the browser, Can I solve this problem ? @Bravo

Comment: reading this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40599069/node-js-net-socket-is-not-a-constructor

Comment: I'm gonna try to use `'net'` for tcp server. I also gonna use `socket.io` in the server side. I gonna use `socket.io-client` in the browser too. after if data comes from tcp server, I gonna send data to browser with `socket.io`. when I want to send data to server from browser, I gonna use `socket.io-client`. I dont know, it gonna able to be.

Comment: @SefaUn - sure, give it a go

Comment: I did it with `socket.io` and `socket.io-client` :)